# Checkbox onChange function does not reflect changed Array data even when other components reflect it

Tags: reactjs, react-native, native-base

This is a rather complicated and bizarre issue. I have an object array with the following format:

```
Array [
  Object {
    "ContactNo": "",
    "Email": "",
    "FirstName": "",
    "IsActive": true,
    "IsChecked": true,
    "LastName": "",
    "NRIC": "",
    "RelationshipID": 1,
  },
]
```

when the user clicks the add button, another copy of the object is added to the array via this function:

```
const concatFormData = (key, values) => {
    setFormData((prevFormData) => ({
      ...prevFormData,
      [key]: prevFormData[key].concat(values),
    }));
  };
```

values =

```
{
    "ContactNo": "",
    "Email": "",
    "FirstName": "",
    "IsActive": true,
    "IsChecked": true,
    "LastName": "",
    "NRIC": "",
    "RelationshipID": 1,
}
```

therefore when it is added the array should look like this:

```
Array [
  Object { // initial
    "ContactNo": "",
    "Email": "",
    "FirstName": "",
    "IsActive": true,
    "IsChecked": false,
    "LastName": "",
    "NRIC": "",
    "RelationshipID": 1,
  },
  Object { // value that is newly added
    "ContactNo": "",
    "Email": "",
    "FirstName": "",
    "IsActive": true,
    "IsChecked": false,
    "LastName": "",
    "NRIC": "",
    "RelationshipID": 1,
  },
]
```

I have a screen component that renders additional parent components (there is one there already by default) each having textboxes and a checkbox child components. each of these child components has a handler function to allow them to update the array according to parent index and field.

Problem: when users add a new parent component via a button, all of the parent and associated child components handler functions reflect the newly added object in the array perfectly. Except the checkbox in the initial parent component(they all have the same onChange handler function). therefore when i click this checkbox. it crashes with an undefined is not a object error.

I troubleshooted and found that the array that initial checkbox shown during the handler function is missing the newly added object:

Should be:

```
Array [
  Object {
    "ContactNo": "",
    "Email": "",
    "FirstName": "",
    "IsActive": true,
    "IsChecked": true,
    "LastName": "",
    "NRIC": "",
    "RelationshipID": 1,
  },
  Object {
    "ContactNo": "",
    "Email": "",
    "FirstName": "",
    "IsActive": true,
    "IsChecked": false,
    "LastName": "",
    "NRIC": "",
    "RelationshipID": 1,
  },
]
```

but got (notice the second element is suddenly missing):

```
Array [
  Object {
    "ContactNo": "",
    "Email": "",
    "FirstName": "",
    "IsActive": true,
    "IsChecked": true,
    "LastName": "",
    "NRIC": "",
    "RelationshipID": 1,
  },
]
```

all the initial checkbox sibling components do not have this error and shows the array accurately.
I troubleshooted for some time and i found the likely cause to be the checkbox component (replacing it with a textbox solves the issue for some reason). code for the checkbox component is as follows:

```
function SingleOptionCheckBox({
  title,
  value,
  onChangeData,
  accessibilityText,
}) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.ComponentContainer}>
      <HStack justifyContent="space-between" alignItems="center">
        <Text style={styles.TitleMsg}>{title}</Text>
        <Checkbox
          isChecked={value}
          value={value}
          onChange={onChangeData}
          //   aria-label=" Do you wish to key in the Date of Leaving?"
          accessibilityLabel={accessibilityText}
          _checked={{ bgColor: colors.green }}
        />
      </HStack>
    </View>
  );
}
```